# How do I categorize material as having uniform or non-uniform tension?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, material-science

From what I've learned tension uniform/constant throughout the body only in massless objects eg: massless ropes, but when is it non-uniform?

EDIT: By uniform/constant tension I mean the value of tension in the object is the same at any point in the object. Non-uniform tension just means the opposite i.e tension at one point isn't equal to tension at another point in the object.

Comment: You are correct,  i don't think anybody can add anything to it . Are you looking for a reason for it ?

Comment: @Binod Yes indeed!

Comment: @Binod You can have uniform tension in a rope with mass, it just can't be hanging under the force of gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massless ropes will normally have uniform tension, since the weight of the rope itself doesn't factor into any tension calculation. Ropes with mass tend to have nonuniform tension, since their own weight needs to be accounted for - the top of the rope has to support everything below it, while the bottom of the rope doesn't have to support anything at all.

You can also have constant tension in a rope with mass, so long as that mass isn't hanging under the force of gravity, which would result in different masses above and below different points and unequal tension. To do this, simply lay the rope horizontally on the floor, and pull both ends - now you have a rope with mass and uniform tension.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for the explanation!

Comment: Actually I have a doubt, I just came across a problem where a solid rod placed horizontally on a surface is subjected to a horizontal force on one side only, I am supposed to find the tension at a point x distance from the side where force is being applied. The answer says tension is a function of x, given by T = F(1 - x/l) where l is the length of the rod. So I am now puzzled as to why tension is not uniform in this case...?

Comment: @Prithvidiamond The tension varies there because you have movement. You can visualize that the part you're pulling on experiences the full tension, as it has to pull everything behind it. The other end of the rod, in contrast, experiences little tension, since it's not pulling anything else. The front of the rod has to transmit a force that accelerates the whole rod, while the back just needs a force to accelerate that last bit. Horizontal orientation can allow for uniform tension, but doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: I see, so what is the condition for uniform tension and non-uniform tension, if it can be generalised like so?